# how to set Multiple one to many relation with same column hibernate

Tags: java, xml, hibernate, one-to-many, hibernate-onetomany

There are two entities.

1. Route (Arrival, ArrivalID and Departure , DepartureID) as Location
2. Location (Arrivals , Departures ) as Route

**Location will have 2 one to many relationship with route table.**

I am trying to set.

Route.xml

```
 <many-to-one name="departure" class="com.nakisa.agency.Location" fetch="select" insert="false" update="false">
        <column name="locationID" not-null="true" />
    </many-to-one>

     <many-to-one name="arrival" class="com.nakisa.agency.Location" fetch="select" insert="false" update="false">
        <column name="locationID" not-null="true" />
    </many-to-one>
```

Location.xml

```
<set name="arrivals" table="Routes" inverse="true" lazy="true" fetch="select">
            <key>
                <column name="arrivalID" not-null="true" />
            </key>
            <one-to-many class="com.nakisa.agency.Route" />
        </set>


        <set name="departures" table="Routes" inverse="true" lazy="true" fetch="select">
            <key>
                <column name="departureID" not-null="true" />
            </key>
            <one-to-many class="com.nakisa.agency.Route" />
        </set>
```

I'm getting error as departureID is null even i set departureID there in route.

How to correct these mappings in order to work

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think you have problem with fetching:

`Lazy="true|false"` controls whether an association is loaded eagerly or on demand.
`fetch="select|subselect|join|batch"` controls how is that entity or collection loaded, when it's required to be loaded.

With `lazy="true"` and `fetch="select"` Hibernate will lazy load the collection and will load it with a select. If you set `lazy="false"`, the same select will be executed, the difference will be that it will get executed eagerly. Hope this makes sense.

Try to set `lazy="false"`, and then see if your `departureID` is still `null`.